# Method invocation may produce 'NoMethodError' in Ruby

Tags: rubymine

I have some code:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'httpclient'

client = HTTPClient.new
response = client.get 'https://httpbin.org/get'

body = response.body

puts body
```

Why RubyMine have warning about Method invocation may produce 'NoMethodError'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a corresponding issue on the RubyMine's tracker so you can follow it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-24592

Answer (score 2):

Basically, any object that doesn't respond to the method that's being invoked will raise a NoMethodError.

```
class Response
  def body
    'hardcoded body'
  end
end

class ResponseWithoutBody; end

p Response.new.body
# "hardcoded body"
p ResponseWithoutBody.new.body
# `<main>': undefined method `body' for #<ResponseWithoutBody:0x00007fe903028e08> (NoMethodError)
```

In your case, if `response` returns `nil`, or any other object which doesn't implement `body`, then you're going to have a `NoMethodError`.

If you're pretty sure, you're never going to get `nil` after invoking `get` on `client`, then you can omit that warning message.